# How to create a fade-in and a fade-out loop with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I am currently using a fade-in method on my program. However I want it to fade-in, fade-out and repeat the same process over and over again.

What do I need to do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $el = $(".intro");
  var text = $el.text();
  var words = text.split(" ");

  var html = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    html += "<span>" + words[i] + " </span>";
  }

  $el
    .html(html)
    .children()
    .hide()
    .each(function(i) {
      $(this)

        .delay(i * 1500)

        .fadeIn(1700)

    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>

  <div class="intro">PREDICT SIMULATE OPTIMIZE</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I tried it and it's not working on my code editor. The words will show when I run the program, but there's no fade in or fade out effects.

Comment: It’s working fine in the code snippet below in my answer. Nothing is wrong here. All good - I will delete my working answer as I can not tell what wrong with your code editor or which code editor are you using. I provided you a working solution exactly as per the question.

Comment: Okay thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what visual effect you seek (the question is open to interpretation) ...

You can set up two mutualy-triggering custom events on the containing div.

To get the timing right, exploit jQuery's `.promise()`, which returns a promise that will fulfill when the current animation(s) are complete.

To start the process, just trigger one or other of the custom events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $el = $('.intro');
    var $words = $el.html($el.text().split(' ').map(word => `<span>${word} </span>`).join('')).children().hide();
    $el.on('fadeIn', function() { // custom event
        $.when(...$words.map(function(i, word) => $(word).delay(i * 1500).fadeIn(1700).promise()))
        .then(function() {
            $el.trigger('fadeOut'); // trigger fadeOut when fadeIn is complete
        });
    }).on('fadeOut', function() { // custom event
        $.when(...$words.map(function(i, word) => $(word).delay(i * 1500).fadeOut(1700).promise()))
        .then(function() {
            $el.trigger('fadeIn'); // trigger fadeIn when fadeOut is complete
        });
    }).trigger('fadeIn'); // start a never ending fadeIn/fadeOut cycle.
});
```

*untested*

The process can undoubtedly be made more efficient, principally by working with the promise from only the final word, but the code will probably get messy.